# How can I get an SVN Connector installed and working with the Subversive Eclipse plugin without an internet connection?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

My workplace uses a closed network, so all software tools have to be manually transferred. I've installed Subversive (version 0.7.9) successfully, and brought in the latest archive for the connectors from here: [Polarion SVN Connector download site](http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/2.0/builds/). I was able to install the connectors in Helios Eclipse by going to Help | Install New Software... | Add... | Archive..., and choosing the connectors zip file. The installation appeared to complete successfully, then it asked me to restart Eclipse. Now, when Eclipse starts up, it pops up the discovery dialog, but then pops up an error dialog with 'Unexpected exception'. When I close that, it pops up another dialog that says something like 'Could not find any connectors. Check your internet connection and try again.'. When I look at the error in the error log, the stack trace starts out like this:

java.lang.IllegalStateException
at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.discovery.model.DiscoveryRegistryStrategy.processBundles(DiscoveryRegistryStrategy.java:89)...

After I close the dialog, Subversive acts as though I have no connectors installed (the connector drop-down is blank in the SVN preferences), even though by inspecting the installed software list and plugins directory, it looks like they're all present. It seems as though the discovery module insists upon trying to find the connectors on the internet, and won't recognize local update sites.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Patrick

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/bv.aspx?ref=SERP&br=ro&mkt=en-US&dl=en&lp=DE_EN&a=http://www.java-forum.org/ides-tools/103547-subversive-helios-problem.html) (original german, translated), the Helios version is not compatible with the Polarion connectors you're using. Try using the ones from the [update](http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/2.0/update-site/) site. Watch out that your javaHL matches your JAVA/machine architecture (32/64 bit) if you use it, otherwise will cause serious issues.

Comment: This may be a pain, because I am not sure the JARs from the update site will install without an archive manifest, but might want to try.